# Specs Pass when run directly, but crash when run in Guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, guard, rails-geocoder

I have a strange situation I can't quite understand.

When I run my specs with `rspec spec` they all pass. However, as of today, when I run guard and it calls the specs, it crashes with the following error:

```
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fourth_env/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1088:in `method_missing': undefined method `geocoded_by' for #<Class:0x00000104fae240> (NoMethodError)
```

Now, the offending line is in my app's `photo.rb` model:

```
geocoded_by :location, :latitude  => :lat, :longitude => :lng
```

This is calling the `geocoder` plugin, which is listed in my gemfile and part of my gemset etc. I re-ran bundler to double check this.

Whether I run `rspec spec` or `bundle exec rspec spec` it all passes, and whether I run `guard` or `bundle exec guard` it fails.

I'm really baffled as to why there would be an error when running specs under guard that isn't present when running specs directly. Has anyone ever encountered an error like this before?

Comment: I wonder are you perhaps running something like spork that can mess with your environment? Maybe you have a slightly different environment in your Guardfile?